# Backlight button not working ( Dell inspiron 14z) - 14.04

Tags: 14.04, backlight

The main point is that everything was working on 12.04 but now I can only change brightness using the applet.

Here's what I have done so far:

Following the info provided on [Ubuntu Wiki Backlight](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight) I have landed on this page [HotKey Troubleshooting](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting).

1. The instructions suggest to kill `gnome-settings-daemon` but this daemon doesn't look to be part of Ubuntu anymore.
2. I have run this command but nothing is shown when I press the backlight keys

   ```
   xev | sed -n 's/^.*state \([0-9].*\), keycode *\([0-9]\+\) *\(.*\), .*$/keycode \2 = \3, state = \1/p'
   ```
3. So I have run `sudo evtest` and selected `/dev/input/event5:Dell WMI hotkeys` and got the following output:
   (nothing happens if I press any of the following keys, except for the `KEY_WLAN`, anyway only the backlight keys are not working on my system)

   ```
   Input driver version is 1.0.1 Input device ID: bus 0x19 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0 Input device name: "Dell WMI hotkeys" Supported events:   Event type 0 (EV_SYN)   Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
       Event code 148 (KEY_PROG1)
       Event code 149 (KEY_PROG2)
       Event code 161 (KEY_EJECTCD)
       Event code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN)
       Event code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP)
       Event code 227 (KEY_SWITCHVIDEOMODE)
       Event code 236 (KEY_BATTERY)
       Event code 238 (KEY_WLAN)
       Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)   Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
       Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN) Properties: Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
   ```

It looks like I have 2 keys provided by `dell_wmi` module for backlight:

```
Event code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN)
Event code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP)
```

What should be the next step here?
In case it is filling a bug some where please tell me where and I will do it .

Comment: When you run `xev`, you need to have the white window active (focused) for the key events to be seen. Was that the case?

Comment: unfortunately no, for other keys is giving me output ...